# WPF bind combobox selected value to a string in a view model

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have this combobox in my view:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding StringObj, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
       <ComboBoxItem>string0</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem>string1</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem>string2</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem>string3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And in my view model I have this string object:

```
    private string _stringObj;
    public string StringObj
    {
        get { return _stringObj; }
        set { _stringObj = value; }
    }
```

How can I bind the selected value from the combobox to the string variable so I can work with it in the view model? This is what I have implemented so far but it doesn't work as I don't understand this binding stuff very well.

Comment: do you get any values at all? (set a breakpoint in setter to check, look into VS Output window for binding error messages)

Comment: Note that the elements in your ComboBox are ComboBoxItems, **not strings**. `SelectedValue` alone will not work (note that you bind against a string property, which will make the binding fail to update). You will also need to use the `SelectedValuePath` attribute to specify the property of the ComboBoxItem objects that contains the string (i.e., Content).

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer? It provides an exact solution to your issue. You can more or less just copy and paste it as is...?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a `string` property to a `ComboBoxItem` value.

You could either replace the `ComboBoxItems` with `strings` in your XAML and bind the `SelectedItem` property:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding StringObj, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <s:String>string0</s:String>
    <s:String>string1</s:String>
    <s:String>string2</s:String>
    <s:String>string3</s:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Or you could simply set the `SelectedValuePath` property to "Content":

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding StringObj, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem>string0</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>string1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>string2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>string3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

This will set your source property to the `Content` of the selected `ComboBoxItem`.